# python - from matrix to dictionary in single line

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

> matrix

is a list of lists with the same length. I've to return a dictionary of the form

```
{i:(l1[i],l2[i],...,lm[i])}
```

Where the key i is matched with a tuple the i'th elements
from each list. 
Say

```
matrix=[[1,2,3,4],[9,8,7,6],[4,8,2,6]]
```

so the line:

`>>> dict([(i,tuple(matrix[k][i] for k in xrange(len(matrix)))) for i in xrange(len(matrix[0]))])`

does the job pretty well and outputs:

`{0: (1, 9, 4), 1: (2, 8, 8), 2: (3, 7, 2), 3: (4, 6, 6)}`

but fails if the matrix is empty: `matrix=[]`. The output should be: `{}`

How can i deal with this?

Comment: Sorry, the last 'k' is actually should be 0. I've fixed this. But it is still the problem if the matrix is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this instead:

```
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[9,8,7,6],[4,8,2,6]]
>>> dict(enumerate(zip(*matrix)))
{0: (1, 5, 4), 3: (4, 8, 6), 2: (3, 7, 2), 1: (2, 6, 8)}    
>>> matrix = []
>>> dict(enumerate(zip(*matrix)))
{}
```

Comment: In this example, the dictionary should include 4 keys (0,1,2,3) since the length of all inside lists is 4. (the inside lists lengths in the same)

Comment: @Sanich: I did some testing with `timeit` and the the above method returned a time of 2.51s, whereas the one you posted returned a time of 23.72s.

Comment: Is it guarantied that 'zip()' returns the tuples in the original order so that 'enumerate()' does the right matching?

Comment: @Sanich: Yes. From the docs: "[zip()] returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables."

Answer (score 4):

try changing part "len(matrix[0])"
This will try look up an index that doesn't exist if the matrix is empty.

instead make it

len(matrix[0]) if matrix else 0

Comment: Thanks!! This is actually the solution i was looking for. Just didn't find the syntax of a condition such this

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution (instead of knowing what's wrong with your one), I suggest you use a list instead of a dict. Seeing as a matrix is fairly static in terms of its size and keys.

This can be done simply by `zip(*matrix)`

```
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[9,8,7,6],[4,8,2,6]]
>>> dict_ = dict(enumerate(zip(*matrix)))
>>> list_ = zip(*matrix)
>>> for key_ in dict_:
...     print dict_[key_] == list_[key_]
...
True
True
True
True
```